# best practice to restrict navigation links depending on the controller and its nested resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some basic user navigation that only needs to be displayed if a user is viewing an Account, or any of its nested resources (members, contacts, etc).  First thought would be to just check if there is an account instance

```
- if @account
   = link_to 'members', account_members_path(@account)
```

but that would also enable the links on new account action, which is a no go.  So, I'd need to hide the links if the @account is not a new record.

This works, but it's ugly.  I could place it in a helper

```
- if @account and @account.new_record? == false
```

But, is there a best practice to perform this check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's common to move the menu into a partial and only render it inside the templates for the other actions.

For something this basic there isn't a "best practice", what you're doing is easy to understand and works, what's so bad about that?

Comment: just didn't know if there was a better way than to have to check if the @account is not a new record every time... like maybe there was a better way to do this I was unaware of